# Method to access/set a session object in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, session, accessor

I currently have the following code:

```
public MyObject SessionStore
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["MyData"] == null)
            Session["MyData"] = new MyObject();

        return (MyData) Session["MyData"]; 
    }

    set 
    { 
        Session["MyData"] = (MyObject) value; 
    }
}
```

I access it using `SessionStore.ThePropertyIWant`

I set it using `SessionStore = SessionStore`

This works; but is there a better way of accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast in the setter, and can make the getter more concise :

```
public MyData SessionStore
{
    get { return (MyData)(Session["MyData"]) ?? new MyData(); }
    set { Session["MyData"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: using ?? is not always a good idea. I used it for a while until I added a List<object> to the session as a property. Then whenever I called the property to add an item a new emtpy list was always returned. If you have a work around for this let me know!

Comment: "You don't need to cast in the setter" - re-sharper agrees ;)

Comment: @WraithNath : I like to use it for simple cases like this. Its like the "?" operator, thou shall not overuse it ;)

Comment: @mathieu - yeah me too :) just though I would mention it incase anyone tried it with a list and wondered why items would not add to it!

Comment: @WraithNath - sounds like the problem was somewhere else in your code, not with the ?? operator itself.

Comment: Seems like the simplest interpretation of what I'd written. Somewhat happy to see its not all that different :op  The other post has merit, but its not quite in the same context :)

Answer (score 1):

SessionStore is fine but you could end up with alot of properties. I tend to add protected properties to base bases and access from there.

eg:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or Sets the Current Order Line
/// </summary>
protected OrderLine CurrentOrderLine
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["CurrentOrderLine"] == null)
        {
            Session["CurrentOrderLine"] = new OrderLine(this.CurrentOrder);
        }

        return Session["CurrentOrderLine"] as OrderLine;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["CurrentOrderLine"] = value;
    }
}
```

then it would appear as a property on your page if you inheriet from it.